# Unity Javascript files open in Xcode

Tags: javascript, xcode, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Using Unity5.1.1 and the problem does not occur when creating a C# script just a JS script.

When I create a .js script and try to open it instead of opening the script in MonoDevelop (even if Mono is already open and running other scripts) the iOS simulator from Xcode will open and then prompt:

```
"The document “[ScriptName].js” could not be opened.
iOS Simulator cannot open files in the “JavaScript script” format."
```

In order to open the .js script through Mono I have to manually open it and go through all of my files to get to my scrip.

Can I explicitly tell Xcode to not open the .js files or tell Mono to open them before any other software?

Answer (score 1):

Select the .js file in Finder, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> for *Get Info*. Click the triangle to open the *Open With* pane. From the dropdown menu, choose MonoDevelop if it's in the list, or choose *Other...* and navigate to MonoDevelop.app. After this, press the **Change All...** button to make sure all .js-files are opened with MonoDevelop. That should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks for the advice.I went into Get Info for one of my .js files. Chose other as it didn't appear in the list and navigated to Mono Develop but it was grayed out and was not selectable. Even with "All Applications" selected I was unable to choose Mono Develop.

Comment: Could be something with permissions... Are you an administrator? You could also try opening en Unity dev environment, choose the Edit menu, Preferences, and General. There you should be able to see which editor unity tries to open your code files with from the dev environment, does changing to MonoDevelop there work?

Comment: Under the external scripts the preferences currently say to open scripts with Mono Develop. Yes, I'm an admin.

Comment: In the bottom of the **Choose application** window, after you've pressed **Other...**, you can pick between **Recommended Applications** and **All Applications**. Selecting All should let you pick MonoDevelop!